# SpringBoot app running in Docker container is not able to connect to Redis hosted on the same machine

Tags: spring-boot, docker, redis

I have Redis and Docker installed on the same physical machine.

I'm trying to run a Docker container with a SpringBoot app inside that needs to connect to Redis. The application fails to start with the following error:

```
2019-08-28 12:25:16.858 ERROR 6 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [app.jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [app.jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [app.jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [app.jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:286) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:469) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:302) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
        at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:226) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:16) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:276) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.11.RELEASE]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:207) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:93) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1767) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:106) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:889) ~[commons-pool2-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:433) ~[commons-pool2-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:362) ~[commons-pool2-2.5.0.jar!/:2.5.0]
        at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:184) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar!/:na]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
```

If I try to connect with redis-cli it works just fine! 
If I try to start my app, with the same configuration, with java -jar on the machine it works fine!

Redis:
Redis 5.0.3 (00000000/0) 64 bit
Running in standalone mode
Port: 6379

Docker:
 Version:           18.09.7
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        2d0083d
 Built:             Fri Aug 16 14:19:32 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

In my redis.conf I have **bind property commented out and protected-mode set to no.**

Comment: What address have you configured for the Redis server?  (Remember that, in Docker, `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` almost always means “this container”.)

Comment: I have configured the public IP of the host macine.

Comment: So as @DavidMaze suggests, you should use *localhost* in order to let Java know that Redis is in the same container.

Comment: They aren't running on the same machine, from the pov of the container. You need a docker-compose file and let the application container use the Redis container and then use the name of the Redis-container in the URL used to make a connection. Don't use `localhost` or the IP of the docker-host.

Comment: I have 192.168.20.150 (the IP of the host machine). Redis does not run in a Docker container but instead it is a standalone service on the same machine as Docker. The IP is accesible from within the container.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is solved by running the docker container with the --net=host flag. It can now access other stuff on the host machine (Redis in this case).